# Auto-mount SFTP share in fstab

Tags: linux, mount, sftp, fstab, sshfs

I have a SFTP share on my server wich use standard authentication.
On my client, I have edited the /etc/fstab file and added :

```
user1@192.168.1.50:/ /mnt/share fuse.sshfs port=22,defaults,_netdev   0   0
```

I mount the share with the command : mount /mnt/share, and I indicates the password.

My question : I have noticed that the share is not mounted permanently. Then, is it possible to mount this share automatically without having to fill in the password each time ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use RSA keys instead of passwords

> 1. Generate RSA keys on the server
> 2. Copy to client
> 3. use the rsa key instead of a password

Comment: Ok, but did I'd have to add the passphrase before each mount ?

Comment: When you create a private/public key pair you have option do not enter a passphrase.